# Sklearn pipeline and FunctionTransformer caused ValueError : could not convert string to float

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, pipeline

I am trying to train a model using the pipeline and transformer function but I get the error below :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "training_model_mlp.py", line 26, in <module>
    bert_mlp.fit(test_uni_verbatim,l)
  File "/home/ge/keloe/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 352, in fit
    Xt, fit_params = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params)
  File "/home/ge/kelo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 317, in _fit
    **fit_params_steps[name])
  File "/home/ge/kelo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/memory.py", line 355, in __call__
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ge/kelo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 716, in _fit_transform_one
    res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
  File "/home/ge/kelo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 556, in fit_transform
    return self.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)
  File "/home/ge/kelo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_function_transformer.py", line 132, in fit
    X = self._check_input(X)
  File "/home/ge/kelo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_function_transformer.py", line 102, in _check_input
    return check_array(X, accept_sparse=self.accept_sparse)
  File "/home/ge/kelo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 496, in check_array
    array = np.asarray(array, dtype=dtype, order=order)
  File "/home/ge/kelo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py", line 85, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
  File "/home/ge/kelo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 948, in __array__
    return np.asarray(self.array, dtype)
  File "/home/ge/kelo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py", line 85, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
  File "/home/ge/kelo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/numpy_.py", line 166, in __array__
    return np.asarray(self._ndarray, dtype=dtype)
  File "/home/ge/kelo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py", line 85, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Pour l’instant, tel que c’est là, c’est bien pour le moteur, mais ce n’est pas utile dans le suivi de pannes telles qu’on les a pour l’instant. On va voir comment le produit va arriver au niveau financier.'
```

lines of code

```
get_numeric_data = FunctionTransformer(get_flaubert_layer)
model = MLPClassifier()

bert_mlp= Pipeline(memory =None,
        steps=[
                ('bert_unc', get_numeric_data),
                ('clf', model)], verbose=True)


path_to_test = "./corpus_test/excel/"
test_uni = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(path_to_test, "corpus.xlsx"))
test_uni_verbatim = test_uni['verbatim']
l = test_uni['etiquette']

bert_mlp.fit(test_uni_verbatim,l)
```

My excel file has  3 columns :  id, verbatim and etiquette (labels) and I just work with verbatim and etiquette column . etiquette column is numerical value (0,-1,1)  and verbatim is text in a form of dataframe.

I tried to execute step of the pipepline sequentially (as below) and it works but somehow putting them in the pipeline caused the below error. Do you perhaps have any idea how to fix it ?

```
vec = get_flaubert_layer(test_uni_verbatim)
print(vec)
l = test_uni['etiquette']
model.fit(vec, l)
print("ok")
```

How the 4 lines above look :

```
[[ 0.46060956 -0.97513837  0.24297135 ... -0.5366192   0.75630784
   0.5271995 ]
 [ 0.46060956 -0.97513837  0.24297135 ... -0.5366192   0.75630784
   0.5271995 ]
 [ 1.1884439  -1.2774088   0.38470426 ... -0.6285471   0.7991357
   0.6472191 ]
 ...
 [ 0.9055288  -0.87319386  0.14174417 ... -0.07077428  0.98827124
   0.2912133 ]
 [ 1.1489016  -0.36950037 -0.6154352  ...  0.04727489 -0.11711404
   0.3081591 ]
 [ 0.813799   -1.1684985   1.1285298  ... -0.75205886  0.8367219
   1.0885886 ]]
ok
```

how get_flaubert_layer is :

```
def get_flaubert_layer(texte):

    #language_model_dir= os.path.expanduser(args.language_model_dir)
    #lge_size = language_model_dir[33:-1]   # modify when on jean zay 27:-1
    language_model_dir = "/flau/flaubert-base-unc"
    #lge_size = language_model_dir[72:]
    #print(lge_size)
    
    
    flaubert = FlaubertModel.from_pretrained(language_model_dir)
    flaubert_tokenizer = FlaubertTokenizer.from_pretrained(language_model_dir)
    tokenized = texte.apply((lambda x: flaubert_tokenizer.encode(x, add_special_tokens=True, max_length=512, truncation=True)))
    max_len = 0
    for i in tokenized.values:
        if len(i) > max_len:
            max_len = len(i)
    padded = np.array([i + [0] * (max_len - len(i)) for i in tokenized.values])
    attention_mask = np.where(padded != 0, 1, 0)
    last_layer_ = []
    for tmp in spliterate(padded, 2000):
        if len(tmp) != 0:
            token_ids = torch.tensor(tmp)
            with torch.no_grad():
                layer = flaubert(token_ids)
                layer = layer[0][:,0,:].numpy()
                last_layer_.append(layer)
        else:
            None
    last_layer_np = np.array(last_layer_)
    last_layer_np_array = np.concatenate(last_layer_np)
    #print("Total of sentences  :" , len(last_layer_np_array))


    return last_layer_np_array
```

Comment: Could you add the function `get_flaubert_layer` to your question, the error seems to be coming from it.

Comment: @AntoineDubuis I added